# Published npm package doesn't show function hints

Tags: reactjs, npm, publish

I have a `utils` function inside my published npm package that exports many functions, The functions look like this:

```
const createBox = ({id, width}) => {
}
```

Before I publish my `npm` package, When I enter `createBox`, I can see all parameters it can take but After I publish my `npm` package and Install it in another project, I don't get any `hints` and After hovering over the function All I see is an `Any` word.
I'm using `ReactJS`, my `babel.config.json` file:

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "edge": "17",
                    "firefox": "60",
                    "chrome": "67",
                    "safari": "11.1"
                },
                "useBuiltIns": "usage",
                "corejs": "3.6.5"
            }
        ],
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

And here is the build:

```
"build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production babel src/lib --out-dir dist --copy-files --ignore __tests__,spec.js,test.js,__snapshots__",
```

How can I build the package so It shows all the function hints including its parameters?.

Comment: Are you using vscode?

Comment: Usually jsdoc or typescript are used to provide types. Minification usually makes it hard to IDE to infer types.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski There is some "ghost" JSDoc created implicitly though just from the function definition. Thats why hinting works when he has the project open directly. But the VSCode js/ts language server doesnt do this on third party js libs by default.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski This is exactly why I was looking for some magic config that might make the package build bigger but the package won't lose its information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using VSCode? I think this is some annoying default. Try changing this setting in VSCode:

```
"javascript.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": true
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using `VSCode`, I changed my setting to what you suggested, It did make some changes and some of the react functions got more informative, But there was no change to my library, and I still can't see any function hints.